# Dijkstras algorithm in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

Building a chart control that uses Dijkstras alg from scratch.  I have scoured the internet trying to understand this algorithm.  I think I finally understand it, but my code is failing to work properly.  Hoping someone might be able to take a peek at this and see if they might know what the deal with it is...

I will paste in three methods as I think that is everything that might be needed.

For starters, I will say that I created my own Vertex datatype.  It contains the ID of the node, the X and Y, a status string, and a parent which is also of vertex datatype, and distance of integer.

```
    //function to populate lists with all the vertices on the graph
    private List<Vertex> getNodes()
    {
        myVertices.Clear();
        //get all non-dg nodes in list
        for (int i = 0; i < chtGraph.Series[0].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            Vertex vertice = new Vertex(chtGraph.Series[0].Points[i]["ID"], (float)chtGraph.Series[0].Points[i].XValue, (float)chtGraph.Series[0].Points[i].YValues[0], "UNVISITED", Convert.ToInt32(chtGraph.Series[0].Points[i].Label), double.PositiveInfinity, null);
            myVertices.Insert(i, vertice);
        }

        //get all dg nodes in list
        for (int i = 0; i < chtGraph.Series[1].Points.Count; i++)
        {
            Vertex vertice = new Vertex(chtGraph.Series[1].Points[i]["ID"], (float)chtGraph.Series[1].Points[i].XValue, (float)chtGraph.Series[1].Points[i].YValues[0], "UNVISITED", Convert.ToInt32(chtGraph.Series[1].Points[i].Label), double.PositiveInfinity, null);
            myVertices.Insert(i, vertice);
        }
        return myVertices;
    }

    //function to return to a list all the adjacents for a specified node.  Excludes parent node
    private List<Vertex> checkAdjacents(Vertex node, int intTransPower)
    {
        List<Vertex> Adjacents = new List<Vertex>();
        int distance;

        for (int i = 0; i < myVertices.Count; i++)
        {
            if (node.id != myVertices[i].id)
            {
                distance = calcDistance(node.x, node.y, myVertices[i].x, myVertices[i].y);

                if (distance <= intTransPower)
                {
                    if (rdbTotalLength.Checked)
                    {
                        myVertices[i].distance = distance;
                    }
                    else if (rdbPathEnergy.Checked)
                    {
                        myVertices[i].distance = getCost(node, myVertices[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myVertices[i].distance = 1;
                    }

                    myVertices[i].parent = node;
                    Adjacents.Add(myVertices[i]);

                    foreach (Vertex p in openList)
                    {
                        if (myVertices[i].id == p.id)
                        {
                            p.distance = myVertices[i].distance;
                            p.parent = myVertices[i].parent;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Adjacents;

    }
```

And here is dijkstras.... currently isn't working properly and I just can't figure it out.

```
private void dijkstra(Vertex start, Vertex end)
    {

        openList.Clear();

        //populate two lists with all the nodes in the graph
        openList = getNodes();
        myVertices = getNodes();

        //adjacents list for each vertex visited
        List<Vertex> adjacents = new List<Vertex>();

        //final list that is populated with the final path of vertices
        List<Edge> shortestPath = new List<Edge>();

        //used in calculating adjacent nodes.  If distance is greater than transpower, then nodes are not connected
        int intTransPower = Convert.ToInt32(txtTransPower.Text);

        //set current vertex as the starting node
        Vertex current = start;

        //set initially to false
        bool pathFound = false;

        //find the starting node from the list of all vertices.  Set it's distance to 0
        foreach (Vertex p in openList)
        {
            if (p.id == current.id)
            {
                p.status = current.status;
                p.distance = 0;
            }
        }
        foreach (Vertex p in myVertices)
        {
            if (p.id == current.id)
            {
                p.status = current.status;
                p.distance = 0;
            }
        }

        //reorder the list to bring the starting node to the first element
        openList = openList.OrderBy(h => h.distance).ToList();

        //openList.Add(current);
        //this.insert(openList, current, true);

        // Repeat while the openlist is not empty and you haven't reached the end
        while (openList.Count > 0)
        {
            //remove node at element 0.  Sorted by smallest distance so it always gets removed first
            current = openList[0];
            openList.RemoveAt(0);

            //if the current node = the ending node, then we have found the path.  Break loop and build the final path.
            if (current.id == end.id)
            {
                pathFound = true;
                break;
            }

            //collect up all the adjacent nodes for the current vertex
            //does NOT include the current vertex we are on
            adjacents = checkAdjacents(current, intTransPower);

            foreach (Vertex v in adjacents)
            {
                float alt =  (float)current.distance + calcDistance(current.x, current.y, v.x, v.y);
                Convert.ToInt32(alt);

                if (alt < v.distance)
                {
                    v.distance = alt;
                    v.parent = current;
                    for (int i = 0; i < openList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (v.id == openList[i].id)
                        {
                            openList[i].distance = alt;
                            openList[i].parent = current;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            openList = openList.OrderBy(h => h.distance).ToList();
        }

        if (pathFound)
        {
            // collect path
            this.foundPath.Clear();
            Vertex last = current;
            while (current != start && current != null)
            {
                this.foundPath.Add(current);
                if (current.parent == last)
                    break;
                last = current;
                current = current.parent;
            }
            this.foundPath.Add(current);
        }

    }
```

Comment: you should start writing unit tests aswell you can use http://www.graphviz.org/ to display the graph for manual debugging :)

Comment: "currently isn't working" Can you be more specific?

Comment: It seems like it's working up to the point where it finds the end node and starts building the final path.  THe idea is that it will take the ending node, look at the parent node tied to it, select that node and identify it's parent, etc.  Until finally it gets back to start that has no parent node.  Then, that should be stored in a path.  From there I can draw lines that will show the path.  But, this is not doing though.  Once it drops in to start calc'ing that final path, it has node id such as: Node1, node2, node3, node3, node3, node4.  So, it can't actually generate the correct path.

Answer (score -1):

I have this method, but it is part for a bigger implementation:

```
public static IDigraph DijkstrasAlgorithm(IDigraph g, int s)
        {
            //Collect number of vertices
            int num1 = g.NumberOfVertices;

            //create an array for vertices
            Entry[] entryArray1 = new Graphos.Algorithms.Entry[num1];

            //for each vertice create new instance for entry of edges
            for (int num2 = 0; num2 < num1; num2++)
            {
                entryArray1[num2] = new Graphos.Algorithms.Entry(false, 0x7fffffff, 0x7fffffff);
            }
            //set vertice origin with distance 0.
            entryArray1[s].distance = 0;

            //create a list for edges
            PriorityQueue queue1 = new BinaryHeap(g.NumberOfEdges);

            //create initial nodes in edges list
            queue1.Enqueue(new Association(0, g.GetVertex(s)));

            //while list is not empty
            while (!queue1.IsEmpty)
            {
                //creates an association
                Association association1 = (Association)queue1.DequeueMin();

                //attributes the vertice
                IVertex vertex1 = (IVertex)association1.Value;

                //if connection is known
                if (!entryArray1[vertex1.Number].known)
                {
                    //checks as known
                    entryArray1[vertex1.Number].known = true;

                    //foreach edge founded
                    foreach (Edge edge1 in vertex1.EmanatingEdges)
                    {
                        //creates the vertex that is being used
                        IVertex vertex2 = edge1.MateOf(vertex1);

                        //catches the weight since vertice in link
                        int num3 = entryArray1[vertex1.Number].distance + ((int)edge1.Weight);

                        //se o peso da ponte for menor que o peso maximo
                        if (entryArray1[vertex2.Number].distance > num3)
                        {
                            //Peso maximo é atualizado para o peso da ponte
                           entryArray1[vertex2.Number].distance = num3;

                            //Define o vértice vizinho 
                            entryArray1[vertex2.Number].predecessor = vertex1.Number;

                           //adiciona o vértice com seu vizinho e o peso entre eles na lista
                            queue1.Enqueue(new Association(num3, vertex2));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Á este ponto, todas as associações foram feitas

            //Cria o objeto grafo como uma lista baseado no numero de vertices
            IDigraph digraph1 = new DigraphAsLists(num1);

            //Para cada vértice
            for (int num4 = 0; num4 < num1; num4++)
            {
                //adiciona o vertice da lista no grafo
                digraph1.AddVertex(num4, entryArray1[num4].distance);
            }

            //para cada vertice
            for (int num5 = 0; num5 < num1; num5++)
            {
                //Se não for o ponto de origem
                if (num5 != s)
                {
                    //adiciona a aresta(origem,destino baseado no vizinho)
                    digraph1.AddEdge(num5, entryArray1[num5].predecessor);
                }
            }
            //retorna o grafo
            return digraph1;
        }
```